# Loging with python without form data

Tags: authentication, web-scraping, python-requests, csrf-token

I want to login to site: 'https://portal.librus.pl/rodzina/synergia/loguj' with requests in python, unfortunately if you inspect and go to network settings it shows main method without 'form data', in addition it has csrftoken placed in script like this:
script type="text/javascript">
var csrfTokenName = "requestkey";
var csrfTokenValue = "MC44MDU4NjQwMCAxdjA0MDk5NtjdKdm32NdksMkfmuMTU0NzZjMTNi1WE1ZmJdfmUdfOpNIlhMDQx";
</script
So i don't really know how to get the content out of this regard you got hundreds of script tags in html file

So the question is how to login to this site?
(i've watched all tutorials on internet, and non of them work)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the request inside network tab and this is the things that I saw (I might have missed some information cause I got error for not having account).

---

1. In network tab if you try to login with non empty values you will have a POST request with name 'action'.
2. Inside this request you will find the URL you want "https://portal.librus.pl/rodzina/login/action"
3. And last part is the form data in the bottom